# Laravel Eloquent. When using With(), how can I pass data to the Model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

My db structure is

**Profile**

- ID
  ..

**Profile_row**

- ID
- Name: eks "First_name"
- Content: eks "James"
- Profile_id: 1

In my controller I do this:

```
$profiles = Profile::with('profile_row')->paginate($request->per_page);
```

and my Profile Model looks like this

```
public function profile_row()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ProfileRow')->where('name', 'first_name');
}
```

And I get a nice nested list with profiles, and every profile_row where name=first_name under.

But how can I send a argument from the controller to the Model where I define what profile row 'name' I want to return?

Eks: Controller (This don't work, but I hope it will show what I'm after)

```
 $profiles = Profile::with('profile_row('first_name')')->paginate($request->per_page);
```

Model:

```
public function profile_row($name)
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ProfileRow')->where('name', $name);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter you `profile_row` model's method to be whithout the `name` parameters:

```
public function profile_row()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ProfileRow');
}
```

When you load relationship with the `with` method add the constraint there.

```
     $profiles = Profile::with(['profile_row'=>function($query) use($name)
     {
               $query->where('name', $name);
    }])->paginate($request->per_page);
```

From the doc https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads